# Converting "$$...$$" into "\[...\]" in emacs with replace-regexp

Tags: regex, emacs

I'm trying to use emacs to convert strings of the form "$$...$$" into "\[...\]". I just started learning to use emacs for this specific purpose for editing some files.

Following the [first example](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ReplaceRegexp#toc1) of replace-regexp on emacs wiki, I intitially tried:

```
 M-x replace-regexp
 Replace regexp: \$\$.*\$\$
 Replace regexp with: \,("\[" \1 "\]")
```

but I received the error: `invalid function "["`. I instead tried

```
Replace regexp with: "\["\1"\]"
```

but I received the error: `` Invalid use of `\' in replacement text ``.

Since neither of those approaches worked, I tried to adapt the [13th example](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ReplaceRegexp#toc13) of replace-regexp on emacs wiki, writing

```
M-x replace-regexp
Replace regexp: \$\$
Replace regexp with: \,(if (evenp \#) "\[" "\]")
```

but I received the error: `(void-function evenp)`. Any suggestions? I'd like to understand what went wrong in each of these instances, and how to fix them.

Comment: `evenp` is part of the `cl` library. Either `(require 'cl)`, or instead use `cl-evenp` with `(require 'cl-lib)`. The latter is recommended nowadays (the non-prefixed names are now aliases), but YMMV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need macros.

```el
(replace-regexp "\\$\\$\\(.*?\\)\\$\\$"
                "\\\\[\\1\\\\]")
```

Or

```
Replace regexp: \$\$\(.*?\)\$\$
Replace with: \\[\1\\]
```

**UPDATE**

1. Used the greedy syntax `.*?` for the cases where there are multiple occurrences on a line (from @phil's comment below).
2. Note that this does not work when the text between `$$` is across multiple lines. If the text is spread across multiple lines the following should work, though at that point I might just prefer rolling my own function:

   ```el
   (replace-regexp "\\$\\$\\(\\(.\\|\n\\)*?\\)\\$\\$"
                   "\\\\[\\1\\\\]")
   ```

   Or

   Replace regexp: `\$\$\(\(.\|` <kbd>C-q</kbd><kbd>C-j</kbd> `\)*?\)\$\$`
   Replace with: `\\[\1\\]`

Comment: I see lots of double backslashes. So when something is in quotation marks, I need to add another backslash?

Comment: Yes :) The \ is a special character in quoted strings as well, for example `\t` is the tab character. To use an actual backslash character in a quoted string you need to use "\\". So "\\$" is actually only two characters, \ and $. Together they mean a literal $, since $ is a special character for regular expressions.

Comment: Okay. Also, to clarify, to achieve what I want I think the `Replace with` line you wrote should say: `Replace with: \\[\1\\]`. Otherwise, it works great!

Comment: This is wrong because `.*` is greedy (the version in the question has the same issue). It needs to be a non-greedy `.*?`.

Comment: @phils you're right. I was getting stack overflow when I tried to use the multi-line version. The correct multi-line version is this: `Replace regexp: \$\$\(.\|\n\)*?\$\$`. However, when I wrote `Replace regexp with: \\[\1\\]` it just replaces the insides of multiline expressions with a new line, erasing all of the other text...

Comment: justin: (1) You're mixing notations here. Single backslashes suggest that you're doing an *interative* replacement, but interactively you can't type `\n` for a newline (you need to type `C-q C-j` to do a quoted insert) -- `\n` is only recognised (by the lisp reader) in double-quoted strings. (2) You're using double backslashes in your replacement, though? That's only correct if you want literal backslashes in the replacement text -- `[` and `]` aren't special in a replacement string, so there's no need to escape them if you only want the brackets themselves. The question is unclear on this).

Comment: justin: Oh, in your comment you haven't grouped the whole match. You want `\(\(.\|\n\)*?\)`. Or `\(\(?:.\|\n\)*?\)` (which avoids the inner group being unnecessarily remembered as `\2`).

Comment: In the replacement text [ and ] have no special meanings, they do not need to be escaped. @phils comment about using greedy operator is correct, I will update my answer shortly.

Comment: Okay. And I did mean to have literal backslashes in the replacement text. I updated my question to show this correctly.

Comment: @MiserableVariable I was just looking at your updates, it looks good. But I actually needed to write `\(\(?:` when I was beginning groupings, because otherwise `\1` referred to the wrong thing when I tried to implement it.

Comment: @MiserableVariable Also, I think you meant to write that you "used the non-greedy" syntax, not the "greedy syntax" :)